# tcl - write out new lines/values between specified points (modification to Brad Lanam's code)

Tags: replace, insert, tcl, text-processing

Context: I've received some remarkable help from Brad Lanam and Glenn Jackman who each developed scripts to convert 25x5 values to 5x5 values (in my .lib file - see below) based on a user defined value. Truly fantastic coding. Very thankful for their help.

Reference: [tcl text processing - rearrange values in rows and columns based on user defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070110/tcl-text-processing-rearrange-values-in-rows-and-columns-based-on-user-defined/23120999#23120999)

QUESTION: I'm attempting to tweak Brad's script (does not currently fully do what Glenn's script does) to overwrite 25x5 lines with the 5x5 lines I've achieved using his script (basically write out a new file with modified values at specified points). Here are the 5x5 lines

```
values ( \
"1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1", \
"6.1, 7.1, 8.1, 9.1, 10.1", \
"11.1, 12.1, 13.1, 14.1, 15.1", \
"16.1, 17.1, 18.1, 19.1, 20.1", \
"21.1, 22.1, 23.1, 24.1, 25.1", \
);
```

**Code that was used in "PART I HAVE TROUBLE WITH" to achieve this**

```
puts "values ( \\"
foreach elem $lines {
puts [format "\"%s\", \\" [join $elem {, }]] # Reference: Glenn Jackman
}
puts ");"
```

Now all I need to is to overwrite the above values in the 'values' portion of the following .lib file (library file format - used in chip design)

**Snippet of .lib file (actual file has tons of lines)**

```
timing () {
    related_pin : "clk";  
    timing_type : setup_rising;  
    rise_constraint (constraint_template_5X5) {
      index_1 ("0.01, 0.05, 0.12, 0.2, 0.4");  
      index_2 ("0.005, 0.025, 0.06, 0.1, 0.3");  
      index_3 ("0.084, 0.84, 3.36, 8.4, 13.44") ;
      values ( \  
        "1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5", \
        "2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5", \  
        "3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5", \
        "4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5", \
        "5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5", \
        "6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5", \  
        "7.1 ,7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5", \
        "8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5", \  
        "9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5", \
        "10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.5", \  
        "11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5", \
        "12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5", \  
        "13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.5", \  
        "14.1,14.2,14.3,14.4,14.5", \
        "15.1,15.2,15.3,15.4,15.5", \
        "16.1,16.2,16.3,16.4,16.5", \  
        "17.1,17.2,17.3,17.4,17.5", \  
        "18.1,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5", \  
        "19.1,19.2,19.3,19.4,19.5", \
        "20.1,20.2,20.3,20.4,20.5", \  
        "21.1,21.2,21.3,21.4,21.5", \  
        "22.1,22.2,22.3,22.4,22.5", \  
        "23.1,23.2,23.3,23.4,23.5", \  
        "24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5", \
        "25.1,25.2,25.3,25.4,25.5", \  
      );
    }
    }
```

I'm writing out the file as I traverse each line but can't seem to figure out how to exactly insert my 5x5 values right after `values ( \` and end right before my ending syntaxes `)` and `}` (and other lines of code in my original .lib file). This effectively 'overwrites' the 25x5 lines. My main issue is WHAT is the right end point (can't be just `);` since there are other lines below it)

**Here is my attempt so far using Brad's code** (please skip to   if { [regexp {values}    )

```
set inFile [open "C:/Tcl/official/draft.lib" r]
set outFile [open "C:/Tcl/official/my_modified.lib" w] 

set inval false
set foundValues 0 # these are FLAGS for later
set extract1 0
set extract2 0
```

## Text processing done by Brad (assume this is all correct - I got the right values)

```
while { [gets $inFile line] >= 0 } {
if { [regexp {\);} $line] } {
    if { $inval } {
        puts $outFile "End of values..." 
    }
    set inval false
}
  if { [regexp {setup_rising;} $line] } { set extract1 1 }
  if { $extract1 } {
  if { [regexp {rise_constraint} $line] } { set extract2 1 }
  if { $extract2 } {
  if { [regexp {index_(\d+)} $line all idx] } {
    regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
    regsub {".*} $d {} d
    regsub -all {,} $d {} d
    dict set risedata constraints indexes $idx $d
  }
  }
  }
  if { $inval } {
    regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
    regsub {".*} $d {} d
    regsub -all {[ ,]+} $d { } d
    set row [expr {$rcount / 5}]
    set column [expr {$rcount % 5}]
    set i 0
    foreach {v} [split $d { }] {
      set c [lindex [dict get $risedata constraints indexes 3] $i]
      dict set risedata constraints constraint $c $row $column $v
      incr i
    }
    incr rcount
  }
```

## PART I HAVE TROUBLE WITH

```
 if { [regexp {values} $line] } {
    set inval true
    set row 0
    set rcount 0
  }

set c 0.084
set id0 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 0]]"
set id1 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 1]]"
set id2 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 2]]"
set id3 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 3]]"
set id4 "[dict values [dict get $risedata constraints constraint $c 4]]"

set lines [list $id0 $id1 $id2 $id3 $id4]

puts "values ( \\"
foreach elem $lines {
puts [format "\"%s\", \\" [join $elem {, }]]
}
puts ");"

############################# INSERTION POINT #########################################

if { [regexp {values} $line] } # find 'values' keyword in .lib as start point
{
   set foundValues 1 
}

if {$foundValues}
{
   if { [regexp {) *;} $line] } # find ' ); ' (end syntax) in .lib as end point 
   {
   set foundValues 0
   foreach elem $lines 
   {
   puts [format "\"%s\", \\" [join $elem {, }]]
   puts $outFile $elem
   }
   }
}
if {!$foundValues}
{
puts $outFile $line
}

close $inFile
close $outFile
```

Will GREATLY appreciate help in this! I'm almost done with this project thanks to the generous help of the stackoverflow community. I will be sure to cite whoever helps/advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem you've got that occurs just at the point where you say you've got a problem…

Tcl ***very*** strongly favours One True Brace style coding. Much more so than most languages. This is because newline is normally an end-of-command marker (and braces are *really* a kind of nestable no-substitution quoting). It also only treats `#` as indicating a comment at the point when a command name is expected (it's still a comment though). Thus, your

```
if { [regexp {values} $line] } # find 'values' keyword in .lib as start point
{
   set foundValues 1 
}
```

Is going to not work. It passes the `#`, `find`, `'values'`, `keyword`, … words as arguments to `if`; the `#` wasn't found as the first character in a command-name position, so it's an ordinary character. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. What you really want is this:

```
if { [regexp {values} $line] } { # find 'values' keyword in .lib as start point
   set foundValues 1 
}
```

I've moved the brace to the previous line, *before* the start of the comment. Mind you, I'd normally write this instead:

```
if {[regexp {values} $line]} {
    # find 'values' keyword in .lib as start point
    set foundValues 1 
}
```

Putting the comment on the next line (or the preceding line) is clearer IMHO.

You could also write:

```
if { [regexp {values} $line] } \
{
    # find 'values' keyword in .lib as start point
    set foundValues 1 
}
```

But that's clunky! I think it's best to try to avoid backslashes where possible.

---

Further down, you write:

```
if {$foundValues}
{
   if { [regexp {) *;} $line] } # find ' ); ' (end syntax) in .lib as end point 
   {
```

That's the identical problem to above. Try this:

```
if {$foundValues} {
    # find ' ); ' (end syntax) in .lib as end point 
    if { [regexp {) *;} $line] } {
```

---

As a general point, if you've got a complicated regular expression, it can be easier to put the RE in a global variable and just use that; it's a simple way to get “named” regular expressions. I personally prefer to use all-caps variable names for such things, but that's entirely your call.

```
set DETECT_END_SYNTAX {) *;}

if {$foundValues} {
    if {[regexp $DETECT_END_SYNTAX $line]} {
```

Like that, it's a bit clearer what the *intent* of the RE matching is (as opposed to just what string it's technically trying to match). In this specific case, it's not too important, but it helps a lot with anything more complicated.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you for enlightening me!